# Дерево решений, алгоритм CART

Tags: алгоритм

Объясните алгоритм CART, готовые программы не нужны, мне самое главное понять суть. Смотрел уже во многих сайтах, но везде как-то сильно по научному написано, хотелось бы более понятное объяснение, с примерами для наглядности.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что Поиск книг, статей, туториалов - оффтопик на сайте.

Comment: Ищите сайты, читайте сайты, разбирайте примеры - а stackoverflow для конкретных вопросов. Это не сайт для сбора ссылок.

Comment: Ну я думал тут есть пользователи которые уже работали с этим и через чат может быть помогут.

Comment: @AK [разве?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-c-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0)

Comment: @tym32167 Насколько я знаю, исключение сделано а) только для книг (тут же сплошные сайты) и б) книг по языкам (тут очень узко сформулированный вопрос). Ну и плюс я в чате спросил, как поступать в данном случае, так как для самого кейс кажется пограничным.

Comment: @AK Автору нужно понять суть алгоритма. Ссылки были в вопросе, а не в ответах, просто для демонстрации, что автор уже пробовал читать. Да и в чате вам так и не ответили ничего конкретного. То, что автор просит ссылки, как мне кажется, это x-y проблема, таких вопросов навалом. Потому мне не ясно, почему этот вопрос должен быть закрыт.

Comment: Вместо [удаления](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/774447/186999) вопроса, его надо было отредактировать

Comment: [там вроде ничего особо научного нет...](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)